# Khan Academy goes into compatibility mode with my proxy settings - solution

Tags: internet-explorer-9, group-policy, khan-academy

I found that when I switched to a new proxy Khan Academy wasn't working on most of the computers in my school any more. I don't know why not all since we all use the same one, but anyway, after looking around for ages I finally found a solution. So, this isn't a question, I just want someone to be able to find the answer faster than me.

I tried - https://sites.google.com/a/khanacademy.org/forge/technical/how-to-disable-internet-explorer-compatibility-view and that didn't help me at all. It wasn't listed, and it didn't say it was using compatibility mode. I assumed it was some sort of JS error or something. It wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

For me the trouble was that for some reason the proxy made IE think that KhanAcademy think it was an intranet site. (or I did that some how) So, IE 9 was by default displaying it in compatibility mode as a result. I fixed that on my local machine in Internet Explorer by pressing Alternate to show the menus. Clicking Tools, compatibility view settings, and unchecking "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"

But I wanted a GPO. - You need to choose DISABLE for this. I thought it would be enable from what the help text said at first. But after reading it a few more times, and testing it, it is DISABLE.

```
Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Compatibility View/Turn on Internet Explorer Standards Mode for Local Intranet
```

is what I read online, but for me with Server 2008-R2 it was

```
Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Classic Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Compatibility View/Turn on Internet Explorer Standards Mode for Local Intranet
```

Comment: Hey, I work at Khan Academy -- thanks for posting this answer! No idea why IE would think that KA is part of your intranet though.